# how to get values from list string in neo4j cypher

Tags: string, list, neo4j, cypher

I have a value of `["1-0", "4-0"]` in a variable score from which I want to get 4 and 0 separately and return them

`RETURN toInteger(trim(r.scoreHTFT[1]))` returns null

Comment: Don't you also want to get "1" and "0' separately? Or do you always want the results for the *last* list element, or the *second* one -- or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: I have found the answer I have been looking for. Thank you for your interest. As of your question I wanted the value 4 and 0 returned not the 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can try for this

```
UNWIND  ["15-2","18-1"] as r
with split(r,"-") as splitFromDash
return toInteger(splitFromDash[1])
```